# css padding issue

Tags: css

I am using this css

```
content#page {
        position: relative;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 22px 44px 34x 64px; 
        background: #fff;
        -webkit-box-shadow: none;
        -moz-box-shadow: none;
        box-shadow: none;

    }
```

I am having an issue with padding. I want it to cover 100% of the screen on the bottom and it should be color white. But it only covers up to certain area. But if I do this change

`padding: 22px 44px 100% 64px;` then it goes to way lower than where I wanted it originally. So I am trying to find a way to get this done in a way so it automatically covers until the end of the page. 
thanks

Comment: If you want to cover 100% of the screen height, how come you don't have `height` in your css?

Comment: Did you set your body and html to be 100% height? DIVs expand to their containers. Without a 100% height container this is not going to happen.

Answer (score -1):

```
padding: 22px 44px 34x 64px;
```

Is missing a 'p', try this if you want 34px padding on the bottom:

```
padding: 22px 44px 34px 64px;
```

If you want the container to extend to the very bottom, then you wouldn't want any padding on the bottom. Correct?

```
padding: 22px 44px 0 64px;
```